# Android how to detect if phone is turned around

Tags: android

This is my code for detecting if phone is turned around or not

```
private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private int orientationLim = 165;

@Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {

            // If shake to stop is enabled
            boolean turnAroundToStop = Utils.getBooleanFromProperties(this, Properties.SP_CB_TURN_AROUND_TO_STOP);

            if (turnAroundToStop) {
                float value = Math.abs(event.values[1]);
                if (value > orientationLim && !stopped) {
                    // Down
                    stopped = true;
                } else {
                    // Up
                    stopped = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but problem is that `stopped` variable is set to true even phone is not completely turned around but just a little.

How can i modify this code that will be executed only when phone is relay turned around.

Answer (score 0):

```
float pitch = values[2];
if (pitch <= 45 && pitch >= -45) {
    // mostly vertical
} else if (pitch < -45) {
    // mostly right side up
} else if (pitch > 45) {
    // mostly left side up
}
```

Take a look here on this topic:

http://www.workingfromhere.com/blog/2009/03/30/orientation-sensor-tips-in-android/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: what about horizontal with the screen down?